# Failed to execute child,getpt failed: no suck file or directory

Tags: android, linux, debian, chroot

I have a debian 8 chrooted for ARMHF. 
Every apps works good but when I try to open the terminal it say's:

> Failed to execute child,getpt failed: no suck file or directory

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1c2u.jpg)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to mount as loop the "/dev/pts" folder...

( mount -o loop /dev/pts /your/chroot/folder/dev/pts )

Comment: Check that your chroot environment has access to both /dev/ptmx and /dev/pts/ptmx

Comment: My chroot does not have "ptmx" in pts